# How to change dropdown language? my language always show Bangla in dropdown

Tags: google-translate

I am using google translate to translate the next js app. but problem is my dropdown menu item always show in bangla. How to convert bangla to English in dropdown.
My code:

```
 const googleTranslateElementInit =()=>{
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage:'en', includedLanguages: 'en,es,pt',autoDisplay: true, layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element');
 }

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" ></script>
```

In my given picture its shows the dropdown List In Bangla.

I am expecting the dropdown shows me English language.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRWbq.png)

Comment: You don't have any picture